# HTTPS POST Connection exception analysis

Tags: java, http, ssl, https

I have written code to successfully connect to a 3rd part service using HTTPS POST using SSL.
The program was successful and I got the intended response.
Problem is that, in our Staging environment, we are getting an exception and I`m unable to debug as we don't have permissions and moreover, the app is deployed as a WAR file; so no source code.

EXception attached.

I tested my working code from a Windows machine and the real test is now done from a Linux machine. The only difference I see is the way the path of the certificates are mentioned.
In windows, it goes something like C://jre-security-folder-path/cacerts but in Linux its somethng like/usr/jre-security-folder-path/cacerts.

As, I`m unable to debug,I`m not sure at which point, it is failing. 
CAn anyone tell me whether this is an issue from my side like SSL certificate related or server side issue?

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:559)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:141)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:394)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:529)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:272)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:329)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:172)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:911)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:158)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1014)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
at com.pass.project.application.activities.DlgEditBoProfilePaxGUIElementActivity.callSecureService(DlgEditBoProfilePaxGUIElementActivity.java:1968)
at com.pass.project.application.activities.DlgEditBoProfilePaxGUIElementActivity.eventStart(DlgEditBoProfilePaxGUIElementActivity.java:301)
at com.pass.framework.utc.components.mvc.activity.GuiElementActivityEvent.callActivity(GuiElementActivityEvent.java:111)
at com.pass.framework.utc.components.mvc.activity.BaseDialogActivityEvent.callActivities(BaseDialogActivityEvent.java:226)
at com.pass.framework.utc.components.activitychain.ActivityChain.fireEvent(ActivityChain.java:141)
at com.pass.project.gillerpax.action.DlgEditBoProfilePaxAction.handleBtnNewtblBoProfilePax_FormOfPaymentAction(DlgEditBoProfilePaxAction.java:4358)
at com.pass.project.gillerpax.action.DlgEditBoProfilePaxAction.handleEvents(DlgEditBoProfilePaxAction.java:423)
at com.pass.project.gillerpax.action.DlgEditBoProfilePaxAction.doExecute(DlgEditBoProfilePaxAction.java:172)
at com.pass.framework.utc.components.mvc.action.CodegenAction.execute(CodegenAction.java:189)
at com.pass.project.gillerpax.action.DlgEditBoProfilePaxAction.execute(DlgEditBoProfilePaxAction.java:127)
at com.pass.framework.utc.components.mvc.forms.CodegenForm.buttonPressedExecution(CodegenForm.java:353)
at com.pass.project.gillerpax.forms.DlgEditBoProfilePaxForm.btnNewtblBoProfilePax_FormOfPaymentPressed(DlgEditBoProfilePaxForm.java:15091)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:191)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:787)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1252)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.pass.framework.utc.components.utcjsf.UtcFacesServletFilter.doFilter(UtcFacesServletFilter.java:138)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at com.pass.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:776)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:705)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:898)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: it is failing on DlgEditBoProfilePaxGUIElementActivity.java line 1968

Comment: I don't believe it has something to do with the cert. You're getting a `connecction refused` error which says the server actively refuses your connection. Either the port is not right or the server is not listening on that port (or  any firewall blocking your request). Please see if you're indeed receiving your request on the server.